# LCD screen display random characters

Tags: arduino, lcd

So I am ultimately trying to build a fun security system using a 4x4 number pad, arduino, and a solenoid. While trying to get the number pad and LCD to work together, I keep running into issues for reasons unknown to me. The code below is what I have so far:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> // includes the LiquidCrystal Library 
#include <Keypad.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7); // Creates an LC object. Parameters: (rs, enable, d4, d5, d6, d7) 

//_________________________________________

const byte rows = 4; //number of the keypad's rows and columns
const byte cols = 4;

char keyMap [rows] [cols] = { //define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypad

  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins [rows] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //pins of the keypad
byte colPins [cols] = {5, 6, 7, 8};

Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keyMap), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols);

//_________________________________________

void setup() { 
 Serial.begin(9600);
 lcd.begin(16,2); // Initializes the interface to the LCD screen, and specifies the dimensions (width and height) of the display } 
}

void loop() { 
  char key = myKeypad.getKey();

  if (key){
    Serial.print(key);
    lcd.print("key has been pressed!");
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
  }
}
```

I keep getting random and broken characters instead though and I do not understand why. Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI9vR.jpg)

Comment: Don't use pin 1 as it is reserved for Tx/Rx! And must not be used for anything but the serial communication.

Comment: It's definitely because of pin 1 as you are using `Serial.print` function, and pin 1 is used as TX on most of the Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LCD Display doesn't display the expected string because you are overlapping a pin which is being used for another task.
The Pin 1, on most of the Arduino Board, is used as a Serial Transmitter (Tx) pin. And this same pin also happens to your one of the pin to the LCD display (rs pin). This causes unexpected behavior and gibberish text on the LCD.

> ```c
> //Pin 1 for LCD
> LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7); // Creates an LC object. Parameters: (rs, enable, d4, d5, d6, d7) 
> ...
> //Pin 1 is used for Serial Communication Tx to send the data via the port.
> Serial.print(key);
> ...
> ```

To properly configure your LCD Display with the Arduino Board, read the documentation from the official Arduino website: [HelloWorld on LCD](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld)

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it was kind of a noobish thing, but I appreciate it a lot. Thanks again!